# Problema: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly. Operação sem suporte. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Tags: c#

Boa noite,

Desenvolvi um programa e preciso implementar a funcionalidade de imprimir PDF.

Fazendo pesquisa na internet encontrei o que preciso, porém tem um problema. Quando executo o código em um programa console separado, ele abre a janela da a opção de escolher a impressora e depois faz a impressão. Implementei esse código no meu projeto, mas está apresentando o seguinte erro:

**Error 1   Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'file:///C:\Trabalho\Projetos\NET\CORREIOS\CtzEmisEtiqCorreios\CtzEmisEtiqCorreios\bin\Debug\Spire.License.dll' ou uma de suas dependências. Operação sem suporte. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131515)   C:\Trabalho\Projetos\NET\CORREIOS\CtzEmisEtiqCorreios\CtzEmisEtiqCorreios\SGEN  CtzEmisEtiqCorreios**

Estou usando dll externas:

using Spire.Pdf;
using Spire.Pdf.Annotations;
using Spire.Pdf.Widget;

Essas bibliotecas anexei dentro da pasta debug e na pasta release do projeto, mesmo assim não resolveu.

O método é o seguinte:

```
  // Bibliotecas externas
  using Spire.Pdf;
  using Spire.Pdf.Annotations;
  using Spire.Pdf.Widget;

  private void PrintPdf(string pstrNomeArqTxt)  
  {
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();  

        //Set the printer and select the pages you want to print
        PrintDialog dialogPrint = new PrintDialog();
        dialogPrint.AllowPrintToFile = true;
        dialogPrint.AllowSomePages = true;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MinimumPage = 1;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MaximumPage = doc.Pages.Count;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage = doc.Pages.Count;

        if (dialogPrint.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Set the pagenumber which you choose as the start page to print
            doc.PrintFromPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage;

            //Set the pagenumber which you choose as the final page to print
            doc.PrintToPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage;

            //Set the name of the printer which is to print the PDF
            doc.PrinterName = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

            PrintDocument printDoc = doc.PrintDocument;
            dialogPrint.Document = printDoc;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }
```

Alguém sabe o que está ocasionando o erro ?

Obrigado

Comment: Como o próprio ErrorLog diz ele não está conseguindo encontrar a Spire.License.dll você copiou essa dll para o seu projeto?

Comment: Bom dia, JcSaint copiei sim.. Consegui resolver o problema no modo debug. Retirei as dll's que estavam na pasta debug e coloquei soltas na pasta bin e funcionou. Agora o problema está no modo release, o erro permanece. Fiz o mesmo procedimento e não resolveu. Estou pensando em o que fazer para resolver agora.

Comment: Diego dá uma olhada neste post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/368384/2588695